# LDAP Proxy with inspection/modification of requests and responses

Tags: tcp, proxy, ldap

I need to build an LDAP proxy that I can program to inspect and modify the LDAP requests and responses - some of the LDAP requests/responses will simply be passed through, but for others I might want to send two different requests to the server and then combine the results (that's just one example - there will be other use cases).

I've looked at the proxying options documented for OpenLDAP's slapd, and I see that it has quite flexible configuration and 'overlays', but no capability to insert custom code.
So I think that's not a solution, unless slapd's source code is easy to modify, to insert my own modules plus hooks to/from the existing code (?)

An alternative would be to start with a friendly TCP/IP framework library (or even a complete TCP/IP proxy). Then I can link to an ASN.1 decoding/encoding library, and write the rest myself.

I'd prefer to avoid having to write (& learn) all the TCP/IP connection/message handling and event loop myself.

So I'm looking for the most complete starting point that does the hard work and gives me the flexibility to write what I need. Typical lazy/greedy approach :-)

Must be open source, ideally in C or C++, and I'll probably be targetting RHEL/CentOS 8 in a container.

Comment: I did something like this with the 
https://github.com/pingidentity/ldapsdk/blob/master/src/com/unboundid/ldap/listener/ProxyRequestHandler.java.

Been a while though and the code. has been misplaced.

We used it to troubleshoot LDAP Client connections.